# How use data from Redux state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactjs-flux, redux

I am new in Redux and React.

I changed data with action and they are changed ! 
I get to React component state. It is as follows:

[image]

How do I extract data from it and use it to render the component?
[New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbAaB.png)
COMPONENT

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {filterChangeTab} from '../../actions/filters';

const FilterPage = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount(){
        const { dispatch, filterState } = this.props;
    },

    handleSelect: function (index, last) {
        return this.props.dispatch(filterChangeTab(type[index]))
    },

    render() {
        const {dispatch, filterState } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="profile-page">
                    <Tabs onSelect={this.handleSelect} selectedIndex={1}></Tabs>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

function select(state, props) {
    let {
        filterState
        } = state;
    return {
        entries: filterState.entries
    }
}

export default connect(select)(FilterPage);
```

Comment: Have you already connected your store to the component?

Comment: My store connected to root component.

Comment: Posting the whole code of the component would support the possibility to write a more specific answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Official documentation

The [official documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#connecting-to-redux) of redux is great and should guide you through your question. I would highly recommend to read through, as the following is just an excerpt.

### Propagate data as props

I assume, that your store is successfully connected to your root component. Otherwise you should check the mentioned documentation again.
Also verify that you installed the [react-redux bindings](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).
With this bindings, you could easily use the `connect`- API to connect your component to the redux store.

In your component you return an object with the entry `entries`:

```
return {
    entries: filterState.entries
}
```

So you have to call this entry correctly in your `render` function:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {filterChangeTab} from '../../actions/filters';

import Select from 'react-select';

const FilterPage = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount(){
        const { dispatch, filterState } = this.props;
    },

    handleSelect: function (index, last) {
        let type = ["all", "categories", "people", "organization", "strength", "curators", "skills"];
        return this.props.dispatch(filterChangeTab(type[index]))
    },

    render() {

        //filterState.getState(); not work

        // Use the correct names!
        const {dispatch, entries} = this.props;
        // Do whatever you want with this value
        console.log(entries)

        return (
            <div className="profile-page">
                            Date range:

                            <Select
                                name="select"
                                value="All time"
                                clearable={false}
                                searchable={false}
                                options={options}
                                onChange={this.logChange}
                            />
                    <Tabs onSelect={this.handleSelect} selectedIndex={1}>
                    </Tabs>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

function select(state, props) {
    const {filterState} = state;
    const entries = filterState._root === undefined ? {} : filterState._root.entries;
    return {
        entries
    }
}

export default connect(select)(FilterPage);
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(state)` inside the `select` function?

Comment: @ViktorPavlenko I updated the answer. Have a look at your `render` function.

Comment: entries is a function? How can i use this function?

Comment: Entries is not a function. Its a value of the object, you return in `select()`

Comment: No is a function, I added img to my q

Comment: I saw your image, but what makes you think `entries` is a function? No I saw the edit with the new image.. anyway..
Could you please replace your `select` function with the following?
function select(state, props) {
    const {filterState} = state;
    console.log(state);
    return {
        entries: filterState.entries
    }
}

Comment: Now, could you please check my comment above? Doing `console.log(state)` in the `select` function?

Comment: Added console.log(store)

Comment: And console.log(state.filterState._root)?

Comment: Added state.filterState._root

Comment: Are the displayed entries the ones you want?

Comment: This is good practice entries: filterState._root.entries[0][0] ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. But do you now understand how to update your return statement of the `select` function? The number of comments is getting slowly very high...

Comment: You have a skype or mail? victor.develop its my skype. Can you help me?

Comment: You could have a look at http://www.reactiflux.com where you could write me a direct message. Same name as on SO.